# How to write a loop in R to decompose a variable value using binary logarithm?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I’m a beginner programming in R, and I want to do the following:
I have a dataframe with different variables. I want to analyse the variable called *Status*. This variable shows the error or the sum of different errors of a measuring instrument.

Errors only can be: 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,0.

- -- 2, 8, 16 & 32 -- are the important errors, that have to be considered and if the *Status* variable of one row of the dataframe contains at least one error of this type, I want to indicate “Not valid data”
- Otherwise -- 1, 4, 64 & 128 -- are less important errors and 0 indicates that the instrument is operating within specifications. If the *Status* variable of one row of the df contains one or the sum of two or more errors of this type, I want to indicate “Valid data”.

For example:

*Status* = 2 (error 2) --> "Not valid data"

*Status* = 26 (errors 2, 8 & 16) --> "Not valid data"

*Status* = 66 (errors 2 & 64) --> "Not valid data"

*Status* = 5 (errors 1 & 4) --> "Valid data"

I’ve tried to do this with the binary logarithm, but there is something wrong and I cannot correct the mistakes, although I think the idea is good.

Here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$Status ==  (2|8|16|32)){
    print("Not valid data")
  }
  if(data$Status == (0|1|4|64|128)){
    print("Valid data")
  }
  if(data$Status =! (0|1|2|4|8|16|32|64|128)){
    res <- data$Status - (2^(trunc(log2(data$Status))))
    while (res == round(res) & (2^(trunc(log2(data$Status))) =! (2|8|16|32))
         & res =! (2|8|16|32) & ((2^(trunc(log2(data$Status)))) | res) =! (1|2|4|8|16|32|64|128))
      {
      res <- data$Status - (2^(trunc(log2(data$Status))))
      if (res == round(res) & (2^(trunc(log2(data$Status))) =! (2|8|16|32))
        & res =! (2|8|16|32) & ((2^(trunc(log2(data$Status)))) & res) == (1|4|64|128)){
        print("Valid data")
        }
      if (res == round(res) & (2^(trunc(log2(data$Status))) | res) =! (2|8|16|32)){
        print("Not valid data")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code, and I would suggest taking a patient approach with it - learn to walk before attempting to run. As such, while I'm posting this as an answer, I recognize that this will not solve the issue you are running into.

The first is that R vectorizes, so you don't actually need a for loop. The `ifelse()` function can help here, but it's not clear what should be returned if there are cases in your data that don't fit any of the criteria. An elegant solution may also be to use the `case_when()` function from the `dplyr` package. You can install a package by first running `install.packages("dplyr")`.

The second is that you can't use `==` if there can be a selection of values that you want to apply the condition on. Instead, use the `%in%` operator. Note also that `=!` doesn't mean anything. If you are trying to use "not equal", you would be using `!=`.

Finally, `print()` is only used to print on screen, it doesn't actually do anything meaningful - at best, it is redundant.

I'm not understanding what you are attempting to achieve with your `while()` code, so I'll leave it as is for now. However, the following bit of code should come close to what you are attempting to do:

```
data$Status_new <- dplyr::case_when(
  data$Status %in% c(2, 8, 16, 32) ~ "Not valid data",
  data$Status %in% c(0, 1, 4, 64, 128) ~ "Valid data")
```

Finally, please make your examples reproducible by providing some data so that we can make sure to provide you with code that achieves what you are looking for. Also, only use the RStudio tag when your issue is with the IDE. Your question as asked does not pertain to it.